# Esper - rule fires twice

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I need some help concerning the CEP engine Esper:
I wrote the following statement:

```
SELECT clientID FROM MovementEvent.win:time_batch(5 sec) GROUP BY clientID
```

And then I sent a MovementEvent into the engine. after 5 seconds, the subscriber is triggered - ok. But after 5 more seconds, it is triggered again - why?

No matter how many events I send to the engine, the subscriber always is triggered twice - after 5 and 10 seconds

I hope you could help me!

Thanx ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
SELECT clientID FROM MovementEvent.std:groupwin(clientID).win:time_batch(5 sec);
```

In general, using GROUP BY without an aggregation function applied to the properties you are selecting will almost always catch you off-guard :). For the sake of it, this statement would also produce what you expected:

```
SELECT distinct(clientID) FROM MovementEvent.win:time_batch(5 sec);
```

This link will probably explain the differences better: http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-reference/html/epl_clauses.html#epl-group-by-versus-view

Answer (score 0):

The group-by makes this an aggregation and Esper provides output when there is a change in the aggregation for the keys, even if you don't select aggregations.
You could do this one

```
select window(*).distinctOf(v=>client) from MovementEvent.win:time_batch(5 sec)
```